# Naming of hierarchical structures in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces, naming-conventions, class-hierarchy

I need advice for the following hierarchical structure, I want to represent in a C++ program.

There is one abstract class `uri` and the classes `url` and `urn` which derive from it.
I would like to have one directory containing the source code of the uri concept. And a namespace which should be called .. `uri`. :)

So, I'm coming to my question.
When the namespace is already called "uri", how would I name the abstract class "uri" then?
What naming convention is usual for this problem in C++?
base, uri_base, basic_uri or how would you name it?

And my second question is. How often can you nest namespaces before users get tedious of it? For example, I've got uri parts like `authority`, `query` and so on..
Would it be wise to create a new namespace (for example: `parts`) and put the source code of this classes in a new subdirectory? Or does this just get "overdesigned"?

Thanks and regards

reeaal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Namespaces are not based nor should they be based on the actual directories that hold the files.
Their purpose is to group related classes/structs/constants together and reduce ambiguities.

There is no problem with naming a class the same as its containing namespace (such as uri::uri). Names should be chosen with the programmer that will use the classes in mind.

Answer (score 1):

> When the namespace is already called "uri", how would I name the abstract class "uri" then?

You can simply name it "uri" if you want, you can have an identifier with the same name as the enclosing namespace with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing namespaces. They are there essentially to prevent name clashes between libraries - you should, in general, have ONE namespace per library.